# Como obtener información de rams instaladas con un arraylist in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2017, core

soy nuevo en c#, estoy haciendo un programa donde obtiene la información de cada una de las memorias ram por separado, ejemplo(numero de serie, nombre de fabricante, tipo de ram, capacidad, etc), lo estoy intentando hacer con arraylist pero no he podido obtener ese resultado.
Lo estoy tratando de hacer dentro de un metodo.

si alguien me ayuda se lo agradecería mucho.

```
    ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
        connection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
        scope.Connect();
        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
       
        foreach(PropertyData data in queryObj.Properties)
           Console.WriteLine(data.Name + "\t" + data.Value);
         }
        searcher.Dispose();
```